# Magento 2 product images are not displayed in the correct order on the front-end

Tags: php, mysql, magento2

Our webshop currently has a few products that have their product images scrambled in the frontend, this could be fixed manually by moving the images and then saving the product however there are about 200 products that face this issue, so I wondered if there would be a way to fix this using a data patch, I already did some research on the positioning see the following.

I first checked the position values in the database table `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` which showed the following result.

[image]

As you can see it shows that the position values for the images are all 0, however after moving image one from position one to two, and then saving the product the result will show the following and will be displayed correctly on the front-end.

[image]

So I would like to save all products that have more than 1 position 0 into the correct order that is in the backend, because the images are ordered correctly in the backend I suspect there is another table that saves the value of the position in the Magento storemanager. However, I was not able to find it. If anyone knows the solution or the name of the table where the storemanager saves backend position values that would be very much appriciated. If you need more details please let me know so I can insert them into my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research into the table I found out that there are duplicated position values in the database this must’ve happened when we implemented a new PIM system, if we remove the duplicated values with position 0, the images show in the correct way in the front-end, now we have to find a way to delete the duplicates in bulk, without deleting the first position 0 element from the correctly specified position row.

The following data patch removed all position 0 data rows that were not supposed to exist. While also keeping the position 0 in the table that has been created first, being the actual image that has to be first in the image gallery in the front-end.

```
$connection = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
$imageGallery = $connection->fetchAll('
SELECT
    row_id,
    record_id,
    store_id,
    position
FROM
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
WHERE
    position = 0;
');

foreach ($imageGallery as $productImage) {
    $rowid = $productImage['row_id'];
    $storeid = $productImage['store_id'];

    $query = "
    DELETE FROM
        catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
    WHERE position = 0
    AND row_id = $rowid
    AND store_id = $storeid
    AND record_id NOT IN (
        select * from (
            SELECT
                min(record_id)
            FROM
                catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
            WHERE row_id = $rowid
            AND store_id = $storeid
            AND position = 0
        ) 
    as temp)
    ";
    $connection->query($query);
}
```

I hope I am able to help other people facing the same issue as me with this answer. If you have a more efficient way of writing the data patch feel free to suggest an edit and I will approve it.